# get a image for yii array

Tags: php, arrays, image, yii

i am a new one for yii framework.i already created menu like this way

```
array('class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu', 
                            'items' => array( 
                                array('label' => 'Home', 'url' => array('/site')), 
                                array('label' => 'Display Menu', 'url' => array('/admin/Displaymenu')),
                                array('label' => 'Reports', 'url' => array('/admin/reports')),
),

                         ),
```

this is a working.but i need to replace Home, Display Menu, Reports by images.i am using CHtml::image also.but it is not working.please anyone can help me solving this problem.thank you for your prompt support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along with using `CHtml::image` try setting [encodeLabel](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMenu#encodeLabel-detail) to false,

```
...
'encodeLabel'=>false,
```

or try doing

```
array('class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu', 
    'encodeLabel'=>false,
    'items' => array( 
        array('label' => '<img src="'.Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/your_image.png" />', 'url' => array('/site')), 
        .....
    ),
),
```

Comment: thank you so much sudhir..you save my time.again thak you so much :)